# Reading n messages from JMS Queue at a time

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I am looking for a solution for below mentioned problem.

There is JMS Queue which stores message, lets assume messages are    m1, m2,...m10k.
When single consumer start consuming messages from the Queue 
It need to read 1000 messages at a time (We are using QueueBrowser)

1. pass m1 to m1k
2. pass m1001 to m2k..

Looking for some suggestions how it can be achieved.